# Are questions about the personal lives of authors, actors, directors and other staff off-topic?

Tags: discussion, scope

The title is my entire question. I couldn't find it explicitly listed in either what's on-topic or in what questions should be avoided. If the decision were mine, I'd consider it off-topic, but nevertheless, I have such a question. If it's on-topic, I may decide to ask it, though it may by some also be considered inappropriate in polite company, so I may decide not to ask it anyway, and try to find the information elsewhere.

Comment: I can’t remember if there was a meta about it (there probably was) but [this question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/190304/58193) having been closed is of interest.

Comment: This question was not well received; [Was Tolkien a driver?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/141084/was-tolkien-a-driver)

Comment: I was tempted to ask a question about [Greg Egan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greg_Egan#/media/File:GregEgan.gif), who famously has no pictures on the internet, but felt that it was probably a bit *too* personal..

Comment: This one was also not especially well liked; [What is JK Rowling "bad" at?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/140363/what-is-jk-rowling-bad-at?noredirect=1&lq=1) and presently sits closed

Comment: Given these comments, I've come to the conclusion that my question is best not asked. If I understand correctly, neither upvotes nor acceptance is rewarded on Meta. Nevertheless I'll happily both upvote and accept an answer saying it's off-topic.

Comment: @InTheAbsenceOfFear - Purely out of curiosity, what was your question?

Comment: @Valorum The sexual preference of a specific actor, whom I've seen portraying non-hetero persons on several occasions, specifically in SciFi and Fantasy. I'm just curious whether they have the same preference IRL. And, since I'm not going to post the question, I'm intentionally vague here, so as to not reveal whom I'd be asking about, nor their gender nor suspected preference.

Comment: @InTheAbsenceOfFear - That sort of question sounds like a downvote magnet; https://youtu.be/YBb4nPLUrOs?t=71

Comment: And to be clear about the intent of the question I had in mind. I have no objection whatsoever to people having other preferences than I do, nor do I object in any way to portraying it in various media. I'm simply being curious about how often it happens that actors have to portray sexual preferences that differ from their real life preferences. Sara Gilbert comes to mind. Her character, Leslie Winkle, on The Big Bang Theory is straight, but Sara Gilbert is, according to [her Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sara_Gilbert), a lesbian.

Comment: @Jenayah And of course it was asked by me!